# Async operation on each file with npm filewalker

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm, filewalker

I'm using [Filewalker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filewalker) to traverse through a directory. However, for each file, I'd like to perform an asynchronous operation. How do I ensure that `done` is fired only after all the operations are complete?

```
filewalker('.')
  .on('file', function(p, s) {
    processAsync(p);
  })
  .on('done', function() {
    console.log('All files have been processed');
  })
.walk();
```

Answer (score 1):

As `on` file event doesn't provide any callback param, create files array and add each file to it. Then on filewalker `done` event use `async` module to process each file asynchronously.

```
var filewalker = require('filewalker');
var async = require('async')

function fileAsyncFunc (file, cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('file processed asynchronously')
    cb()
  }, 100)
}

function doneProcessingFiles (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err)
  }
  console.log('done processing files asynchronously')
}

const files = []
filewalker('./node_modules/filewalker')
  .on('file', function(p, s) {
    //  add file to files array
    files.push({p,s})
  })
  .on('done', function() {
    //  call async functions to each file
    async.each(files, fileAsyncFunc, doneProcessingFiles)
  })
.walk();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm currently doing. I was wondering if there was another way to do it. Thank you for your answer :)